# Разбивка слова на символы и увеличение каждого символа в слове на один с новой строки

Tags: java

Камрады, приветствую. Осваиваю java core. Делаю задание в котором нужно:
Вывести в консоле строки, состоящие из введенных символов. Строка вводится с клавиатуры. Например, слово "Шар". Должно получиться:
Ш
АА
РРР

Мозгов хватает пока только на это. Понимаю, что нужны два цикла, но уже голову сломал.

```
package s01;

public class Task01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "шар";
        char[] array = new char[str.length()];
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < str.length(); i += 0, j++) {
                array[i] = str.charAt(j);
                array[j] = str.charAt(i);
                System.out.println(array);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем увеличивать і аж на 0?

Comment: Обязательно на символы разбивать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правда без разбивки, ибо ну а зачем, думаю под нее сами сможете переделать, если нет, пишите, отпишу второй вариант.

```
class testS {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "шар";
    str=str.toUpperCase();

    String strNew = "";

    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<i+1;j++) {
            strNew += str.charAt(i);
        }
        strNew+=" ";
    }
    System.out.println(strNew);
}
}
```

Comment: Никогда не изменяйте переменные цикла в теле цикла! Внутренний цикл от 0 до і+1. Никаких inc!

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець , все исправлю, только причину отпишите

Comment: Это источник ошибок. Когда разработчик читает код, он не ожидает что переменная или условие будет меняться в теле цикла. Это просто негласные правила.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець , спасибо за ответ ), не слышал еще о таком, возьму на заметку

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем за помощь!
Взял за основу код, предложенный ранее, немного изменил его и добавил разбивку на символы Теперь код выглядит так:

```
package s01;

    public class Task01 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String str = "шар";
            char[] array = new char[str.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
                    array[j] = str.charAt(i);
                }
                System.out.println(array);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть хороший метод `fill()` из класса `Arrays`. Он работает намного быстрее, если вдруг вы вместо слова из 3 букв захотите задать строку в 100500 символов.

```
String str = "шар";
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char[] array = new char[i + 1];
    Arrays.fill(array, str.charAt(i));
    System.out.println(array);
}
```

Comment: вот хороший ответ

Comment: Спасиб, я старался помочь )))

Comment: полезно же узнавать новое, а тут в случае новичков самое оно